# BigDecimal stripTrailingZeros support in GWT

Tags: gwt, bigdecimal

I am trying to use the stripTrailingZeros() method of BigDecimal in GWT but it looks as if it is not supported by the JRE emulator. In the GWT dev mode console I get the following:

[ERROR] Errors in file...
LINE 585: The method stripTrailingZeros() is undefined for type BigDecimal

I am using GWT 2.0.4. Does anybody else have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigDecimal is only emulated in 2.1.0 onwards: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/release-notes.html